# How to add a new field in a node-red message payload?

Tags: node-red, payload

I am trying to modifying a message payload in node-red by adding a new field coming from the `global.context`. For example given the as input the following `message.payload`

```
{"field1" : 5}
```

and assuming the global context has a field `{"lot" : {"f1" : 4, "f2" : 4}}`

I want as output:

```
{
  "field1" : 5,
  "lot" : {"f1" : 4, "f2" : 4}
}
```

I would like to do it without using the `function` palette.
As far as I understand this must be done with the `change` setting `move` `global.context` to `msg.payload` overwrites completely the message so that it results in final message payload being

```
{"lot" : {"f1" : 4, "f2" : 4}}
```

How is a new field-value pair added to the message payload?

Answer (score 1):

You are close to a solution... but instead of overwriting the entire `msg.payload` object, use a `change` node configured to "Set" `msg.`**payload.lot** - to - `global.`**lot** (or whatever the name of the global variable is).

This should create the new "lot" property inside the msg.payload object -- but beware that this will *only* work if `msg.payload` is already an object. Trying to add a new property to a string or number payload will have no effect, since JavaScript treats that as a noop.

Comment: Thank you: maybe I have understood. But I need a further step: suppose I want to modify the global context adding a new field using data coming from an http request. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Sure -- wire the `http in` node to a change node that sets `global.`**lot** to some value passed into the request (use a `debug` node set to show the full msg object and copy the "path" to the value -- then use that path in your change node).

Comment: Sorry what I meant is that both the field name and the data come from the http request. For example I have `global.context.lot.cams` which is supposed to be an array such as `{"id0" :{ ...}, "id1" : {...} }`. Now I built from the request a new object but the field name comes from http parameter. So in the `change` node I would have to do something like `Set` `global.context.lot.cam.[idComingFromHTTPRequest]` to the object value I built.